# Strange rendered texture of tea fluid

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have a question about the rendered texture of my tea fluid.

[image]

Why do I have this weird blurry texture of my tea fluid?

I have copied the surfaces from the cup's inside and added a face on top of the surface. The fluid texture can be seen in the attached figure.

[image]

When I render the whole scene with the cup, fluid, walls and surface light this is the result. I still see this blurry texture which is confusing me.

When I rotate the camera, some of the blurry areas disappear. This is very strange

[image]

Since I am quiet new to Blender, I don't know how to improve this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you very much for your reply. In the rendered result I have already scaled the fluid slightly inside of the cup. Alt-S unfortunately did not changed anything.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for sharing the upload link. Here is the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3vnZ3Vas/

Comment: this looks like the reflection of the floor surface to me

Comment: Yes, I this blurry area seems to be the reflection of the floor surface. How can I edit/modify the refection of the ground surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think there are two things going on here:

1. CG technical. There is a noisy reflection of the ground-plane. That can be improved by [Denoising](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html), and the [other considerations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html) for reducing noise. You might also consider discriminating between rays: sampling at different levels according to the [Light Paths](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html?highlight=light%20paths) the renderer is evaluating, if you find you are having to push the overall sampling rate too high.
2. Perceptual. I think this is more important, actually, here. This all depends on what kind of shot you want: an idealized product or pack-shot, or the glass in a more fully-realized scene. At the moment, in the absence of context, the eye interprets the reflection of the floor, noisy or not, as a feature of the surface of the glass, rather than a reflection of its environment.

For a product-shot, you could, for example, make a full soft box, (an emissive  rounded cube containing the scene)  you can subdivide its faces, delete some, color some, whatever you like, and it can be visible in lighting, refractions, and reflections without being visible to the camera. Your best references probably come from real-world commercial photography. Other devices available to you are depth-of-field, to soften reflections from a distance and emphasise the scale of your object, flags / gobos  for detailed shadows.. reflective or emissive 'cards' to punch up the glow in the liquid ... the list is endless.

At its crudest, the more fully realised scene is less work: put the glass and the floor into an HDRI environment. This is no great shakes, but it took no time.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer Robin. I'll probably try out first the more fully realized scene since it is really looking nice.